# Using typeof as a generic type argument

Tags: c#, .net, generics, typeof

According to the documentation of [typeof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/58918ffs.aspx):

> [...] To obtain the run-time type of an expression, you can use the .NET Framework method `GetType`

Therefore, this means that `typeof` must be a *compile-time* expression.

In the article about [Generic Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx), it is stated that:

> [...] The type argument for this particular class can be any type recognized by the compiler.

Any type recognized by the compiler is any type inferred by the compiler, i.e. any type that is known at *compile time*.

If this is true, then why does the following statement is not allowed?

```
int value = GenericMethod<typeof(int)>();
```

Comment: Because `typeof()` returns you a `Type` object that represents the argument. It is not a type itself. It's also an expression, which is not allowed in that spot according to the C#LS.

Answer (score 3):

typeof() returns a Type object, just like .GetType() would, it cannot be used in place of a type. What you could do though is put `<T>` after your class name, then:

```
T value = GenericMethod<T>();
```